# New compilation errors with react-addons-test-utils

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Updating to the latest .d.ts definitions for react-addons-test-utils has broken compilation for our test code. In this function:

```
import * as TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import MyReactComponent from 'blabla'

let buildComponent = () => {
    const root = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyReactComponent/>);
    return TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(root, MyReactComponent);
}
```

Passing `root` to the last function here causes `error TS2345: Argument of type 'Component<any, {}> | Element | void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<any, any>'.`

Fine, I can cast:

```
let buildComponent = () => {
    const root = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyReactComponent/>);
    return TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(root as React.Component<any, any>, MyReactComponent);
}
```

But now passing `MyReactComponent` on the last line causes `error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof MyReactComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<{}> & (new () => MyReactComponent) & (new () => { props: any; })'.`

Apparently it expects a `ClassType<any, T, C>` where `C extends ComponentClass<{}>`, and somehow my `class MyReactComponent extends React.Component<IMyReactComponentProps, IMyReactComponentState>` doesn't fit the bill, but how, I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

> not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'

This means that `root` Should be of type `React.Component<any,any>`. This means the signature of `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` is probably wrong.

## Hack:

```
import * as TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import MyReactComponent from 'blabla'

let buildComponent = () => {
    const root: React.Component<any, any> = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyReactComponent/>) as any;
    return TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(root, MyReactComponent);
}
```

## More

Note the use of `any` is needed as there is no simple structural relationship between the return value and desired return value. See https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, following helped:

```
TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(root as React.Component<any, any>, MyReactComponent as any);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the breaking change and fluidity of both React and the definition files, we might give it a bit of help (and maybe simplify fixes to future changes) by abstracting use of the 3rd-party methods beneath explicitly-typed helpers. We lose some of the "flexibility" in the current definitions, but if we *know* the return type from `renderIntoDocument` and the parameter types for `findRenderedComponentWithType` (for instance), we could define wrappers like so:

```
function renderIntoDocument (reactEl: React.ReactElement<{}>) {
  return TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(reactEl) as React.Component<{}, {}>
}

function findRenderedComponentWithType(root: React.Component<{}, {}>, type: React.ComponentClass<{}>): React.Component<{}, {}> {
  return TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(root, type as any)
}

let buildComponent = () => {
  const root = renderIntoDocument(<MyReactComponent/>);
  return findRenderedComponentWithType(root, MyReactComponent);
}
```